# Why is JS not scrolling to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am pretty new to code. I am making a personal website and I want a menu that, when you click on the a certain topic, automatically scrolls to that part on the site. I come from the graphic designer world.

When you click on contact, it does what it's supposed to. But when you click on Explore, it goes to a position not at the top, but a bit below. I want it go to to the top, but for some reason it doesnt work. Most of my JS i got from Stackoverflow btw.

BTW image looks a bit weird, thats because of the window resolutions of the snippet. need to find a way to fix that too.

What I want: ***when clicking on the menu at the upper left corner, and then explore, the page has to smooth-scroll to the top.***

**Just try it out on the snippet, you'll understand my problem.**

*(I am using safari, macOS)*

```js
function myFunction() {
    if($("#myDropdown").is(":visible")){
        $("#myDropdown").fadeOut(); 
    } else {
        $("#myDropdown").fadeIn();
    }
   }
   
   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
   
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      $("#myDropdown").fadeOut();
    }
   }
   }
   
   $(function()
   {
   $("#btnButton1").click(myFunction);
   });
   
   $("a[href='#bottom']").click(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
   return false;
   });
   
   $("a[href='#']").click(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  $(functionid).height() }, "fast");
   return false;
   });
```

```css
#btnButton1:hover + #img {
   opacity: 0.7;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   #drpbtn:hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   .Menu {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: fixed;
   top: 17px;
   left: 17px;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index:5;
   color: white;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   button:focus {outline:0;}
   .dropbtn {
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   position: fixed;
   top: 17px;
   left: 17px;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: transparent;
   z-index: 6;
   color: white;
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   }
   .dropdown {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   }
   .dropdown-content {
   z-index: 3;
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #141414;
   min-width: 160px;
   overflow: auto;
   box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   top: 60px;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
   backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
   }
   .dropdown-content a {
   color: white;
   padding: 13px 18px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   font-weight: 200;
   opacity: 1;
   transition: color .3s;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   }
   .dropdown a:hover {
   color: #a3a3a3;
   transition: color .3s;
   }
   .show {
   display:block;
   }
   .Logo {
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 6;
   left: 50%;
   top: 14px;
   opacity: 1;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   .Logo:hover, .Logo:focus {
   opacity: 0.7;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   .Menu:hover {
   opacity: 0.7;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   .back {
   left: 0%;
   top: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
   .fixedbar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 4;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
   backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   }
   .contact {
   margin-top: 36px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 3;
   top: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   color: black;
   font-size: 16px;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   font-weight: 200;
   }
   .info {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 6;
   top: 100%;
   margin-top: 78px;
   left: 50%;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   color: black;
   font-size: 14px;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: 200;
   }
   .info a:link {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
   .info a:visited {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
   .info a:hover {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: underline;
   }
   .info a:active {
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
   }
   .insta {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 6;
   top: 100%;
   margin-top: 118px;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);
   transition: filter .3s;
   opacity: 1
   }
   .insta:hover, .insta:focus {
   opacity: 0.7;
   transition: opacity .3s;
   }
   .contactb {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   top: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   height: 162px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
   <title color="white">
      dnsvnr 
   </title>
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png?v=jwL2yROogB">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=jwL2yROogB">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png?v=jwL2yROogB">
   <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest?v=jwL2yROogB">
   <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=jwL2yROogB" color="#5bbad5">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=jwL2yROogB">
   <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#5bbad5">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#5bbad5">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="btnButton1" class="dropbtn" >
      </button>
      <img id="img"src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/Menu.png" width="24" height="24" class="Menu" />
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="/">Home</a>
         <a id="functionid" href="#">Explore</a>
         <a id="document" href="#bottom">Contact</a>
      </div>
   </div>
<body>
   <a href="/"><img src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/logo.png" class="Logo" width="32" height="32"/></a>
</body>
<back class="background"></back>
<nav class="fixedbar"></nav>
<center id="contact" class="contact"> Contact </center>
<center class="info">
   <a href="mailto:info@dnsvnr.com">email: info@dnsvnr.com</a>
</center>
<a href="http://www.instagram.com/dnsvnr" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/insta.png"   class="insta" width="16" height="16"/></a>
<nav class="contactb"></nav>
<img class="back" src="http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fthtsi-assets-production/ez/images/8/3/6/5/125638-1-eng-GB/main_6e766fc6-3097-4df1-93a9-4228f60f2f27.jpg">
```

Comment: "Just try it out on the snippet, you'll understand my problem." - nope, sorry, I opened your snippet and I have no idea where to click to see your issue.

Comment: You have a bunch of elements outside of the `<body>` tag that do not belong outside it (its considered invalid html). And even inside the `<head>` where they do not belong. The browser will try to do error correction, but may not always fix it correctly. Also you do not need to include full html in snippets, eg `<head>`,`<body>` tags. Those are generated by taking the various code you enter into the editor

Comment: I meant upper left corner, Liora! Sorry.

Comment: Click on the icon at the upper left, click explore and watch. What happened is that the page scrolled down a bit. I don't want that. I want it to scroll to the extact top.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `functionid` inside one of the click functions is not defined, so it is giving you unexpected behavior. Was that meant to be an ID selector?

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:  $("#functionid").height() }, "fast");
  return false;
});
```

Also, if you wanted to send the scroll to the top of the document, `scrollTop` could just be set to `0`.

Comment: Ehmmm.... I am so new to code... how do i set it to 0? I have tried multiple things.

Comment: You would change the part of the line that says `scrollTop:  $("#functionid").height()` to `scrollTop:  0`. Make sense?

Comment: Here's the fiddle I worked it out with: https://jsfiddle.net/ep30xdq2/9/

Comment: Yeah, it kinda does. CSS makes sense for me, html kinda but JS I need to learn

Comment: @Henh the fiddle in the link I shared has a working example. Maybe looking at that will help.

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate you helping a stranger out so much! Whenever I have much knowledge about code I'll promise to do the same!